# Pegar elementos HTML de um url e mandar para uma div

Tags: javascript

Como pegar elementos com uma `id` especifica, e pegar todos os elementos que estão dentro de uma `url` e mandar para uma `div`(não `iframe`)? É possível com JavaScript puro, ou é necessário alguma biblioteca js? Por onde devo começar?.
Exemplo eu quero pegar elementos dessa url https://sopt.stackexample.ml/copiar.html ou dessa https://sopt.stackexample.ml/copiar e enviar para uma `div`

**Exemplo de onde quero chegar, porém usando um elemento na mesma pagina:**

```js
function copiar() {
  document.getElementById("div1").innerHTML = document.getElementById("div").innerHTML
}
```

```html
<button onclick="copiar()">CLIQUE</button>
<div id="div">Texto</div><div id="div1"></div>
```

> OBS: Tenho acesso a pagina de onde quero pegar os elementos

Answer (score 2):

Você pode utilizar o `XMLHttpRequest` ou `Fetch` para realizar uma requisição de obter o código fonte da página. Após isso, basta utilizar `document.createElement` ou `DOMParser` para poder "converter" o código fonte retornado (como *string*) para *HTML*.

---

**Exemplo com `XMLHttpRequest` e `document.createElement`:**

`XMLHttpRequest` é uma API que fornece funcionalidade ao cliente para transferir dados entre um cliente e um servidor. Ele fornece uma maneira fácil de recuperar dados de um URL sem ter que fazer uma atualização de página inteira. Já o `document.createElement` irá criar um elemento *HTML*, dessa forma podemos utilizar funções como `querySelector` e filtrar determinados elementos.

**JavaScript:**

```
const result = document.querySelector("#result")
const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

xhr.addEventListener("load", event => {

  /**
   * Cria um elemento temporário
   * Adiciona o código fonte retornado
   */
  const html = document.createElement("html")
  html.innerHTML = event.target.response
  
  /* Captura todos os links com o atributo rel="bookmark" */
  const anchors = html.querySelector("a[rel=\"bookmark\"]");
  
  /* Adiciona os links capturados na div#result */
  anchors.forEach(anchor => {
    result.innerHTML += anchor
  })
  
})

function copy() {
  /* Realiza a requisição */
  xhr.open("GET", "https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/")
  xhr.send()
}
```

**JavaScript:**

```
<button onclick="copy()">Click!</button>

<div id="result"></div>
```

---

**Exemplo com `Fetch` e `DOMParser`:**

A *Fetch API* fornece uma interface para buscar recursos (por exemplo, em toda a rede). Parecerá familiar para qualquer pessoa que tenha usado *XMLHttpRequest*, porém a nova *API* oferece um conjunto de recursos mais poderoso e flexível. A função `DOMParser` irá converter nossa *string* para *HTML*, dessa forma poderemos utilizar funções como `querySelectorAll` para filtrar os elementos úteis.

**JavaScript:**

```
const result = document.querySelector("#result")

function copy() {
    fetch("https://developer.mozilla.org/")
        .then( response => response.text())
        .then( response => {
            
            /**
            * Cria um elemento temporário
            * Adiciona o código fonte retornado
            */
            const parser = new DOMParser()
            const html = parser.parseFromString(response, "text/html")

            /* Captura todos os links com o atributo rel="bookmark" */
            const anchors = html.querySelector("a[rel=\"bookmark\"]")

            /* Adiciona os links capturados na div#result */
            anchors.forEach(anchor => {
                result.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', anchor)
            })
        })
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<button onclick="copy()">Click!</button>

<div id="result"></div>
```

---

**Restrição:**

Por questões de segurança, os navegadores estão bloqueando requisições em páginas que não possuem o cabeçalho `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`.

[image: Diagrama de Uso]
<sub>(fonte: [mozillademos.org](https://mdn.mozillademos.org/files/14295/CORS_principle.png))</sub>

Para mais detalhes recomendo a página [Controle de Acesso HTTP (CORS)](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS).